# User namespace error - /dev/pts mode change

Tags: namespace

I am doing a simple test on user namespace on Ubuntu 16.04 as shown below.

```
root@PC:/# 
root@PC:/# unshare --user --map-root-user
mesg: change /dev/pts/2 mode failed: Operation not permitted
root@PC:/#
```

I want to ask if anyone knows why the error "change /dev/pts/2 mode failed: Operation not permitted" occurs. I checked online and found [this](https://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/m2rNsxvr/dev-pts-0-operation-not-permitted) answer, but my filesystem does not have any `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: It may still have a `~/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`). It's clear that `mesg` is called from some initialization script. I bet that you won't see any such message if you run it as `unshare --user --map-root-user bash --norc`.

Comment: Yes I don't see any error message when I run `unshare --user --map-root-user bash --norc`